# do I need to include jquery version file to use jquery.ui.js?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use jquery-ui widgets and so I am including jquery.ui.js. Would I also need to include jquery version file as well?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery.UI you have to include jQuery.js.

[jQuery.UI](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ui) is a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you want to do.  If you just need basic DOM manipulation, even handling, and things like that, then use jquery.js.  If you need advanced UI components and functionality (dragging and dropping, sorting, etc.) then you'll probably need jquery.ui.js.

**EDIT** My mistake on misreading the question.  Yes, you need jquery.js for jquery.ui.js